# How to handle floating point number in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I read that there is no support for floating point number in solidity, So how we can handle it. If I want to store 12.23 or something like that.

Comment: Answered similar question recently - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70898/handling-decimals-in-somewhat-complex-math/70908

Comment: Store 1223 and 100, and use them wisely (i.e., always postpone the part where you divide by 100 as much as possible, without changing the actual expression being calculated).